# error al Compilar: System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes:  tengo un Ws, que hace rato no lo tocaba. hoy quise agregarle algo y al compilar, me devuelve el sig error:

Build (web): The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.

Estuve googleando pero no puedo encontrar el error.
En Vs estoy como admin.-

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado IIS?.

Comment: Hola. Si tengo instaladado IIs Express.